# Getting rich autocomplete value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I´m trying to implement a richfaces dataTable.
Each row has a richfaces calendar, two richfaces autocomplete, and 3 input texts.

I have a command button in another form.
When I enter some values in a given row of the data table:

- a valid date is displayed
- the two autocpmpletes work fine to retrieve data selection from the bean
- I enter value in the input texts

But when I click on the "Compute" button
only the text inputs are sent back to the backing bean.

Here is so far what I came up with (this is a simplified version of my xhtml file)

```
<h:body>
    <rich:panel>
                <h:form id="legForm">
                    <rich:dataTable value="#{bean.legsForDisplay}" var="legForDisplay">
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Departure Date (UTC)" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <rich:calendar value="#{legForDisplay.departureTime}"
                                locale="#{bean.locale}" popup="true"
                                datePattern="#{legForDisplay.datePattern}"
                                converter="dateConverter" inputStyle="width:80px">
                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"/>
                            </rich:calendar>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="ETD (HHmm)" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:inputText value="#{legForDisplay.etd}" style="width : 30px;">
                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="ADEP" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="2"
                                autocompleteMethod="#{bean.autocomplete}"
                                autofill="false" value="#{legForDisplay.adep}">
                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"/>
                            </rich:autocomplete>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="ADES" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" minChars="2"
                                autocompleteMethod="#{bean.autocomplete}"
                                autofill="false" value="#{legForDisplay.ades}">
                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"/>
                            </rich:autocomplete>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Male Pax" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:inputText value="#{legForDisplay.malePax}">
                                <f:ajax />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Female Pax" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:inputText value="#{legForDisplay.femalePax}">
                                <f:ajax />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Child Pax" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:inputText value="#{legForDisplay.childPax}">
                                <f:ajax />
                            </h:inputText>
                        </rich:column>
                    </rich:dataTable>
                </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
    <rich:panel>
        <h:form>
            <a4j:commandButton value="Compute Mission"
                action="#{bean.doStuff}"
                render="@form">
            </a4j:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</h:body>
```

How can I set the values from the calendar / auto complete components into the corresponding `legForDisplay` element from the `legsForDisplay` List ?

I tried to read all the related questions on the subject, but couldn't find a solution to this problem, which seems rather basic ...

thanks

EDIT :

If a put a dummy submit button inside the rich data table, everything works. I can press this dummy button, and then the "compute Mission" and the values are already stored in the bean.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
    action="#{missionHandler.dummySubmit}" limitRender="true"
    render="legTable">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

My concern is that I want to submit from the "Compute Mission" button, which is located in another panel, in another form, WITHOUT clicking on the "dummy button" first.

Comment: I encapsulated everything in a BIG form. It works, because when I press the "compute" button, the BIG form is submitted, and the values are retrieved. Not sure it is the best thing to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this without BIG form:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" execute="legForm"
   action="#{missionHandler.dummySubmit}" limitRender="true"
  render="legTable">
</a4j:commandButton>
```